# Undefined error in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I'm getting data from XML. I can successfully pick up a price from the XML but there is a unexpected error called undefined that shows up when I use the function given below;

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function myXml(origin, destination) {
        var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("flights");

        for(i=0;i<x.length;i++) {
          if(x[i].getAttribute('FrTLAs')==origin && x[i].getAttribute('destination')==destination) {
            document.write(x[i].getAttribute('price'))
          }
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.write(myXml('SYD','Bali'));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: if xml is not defined so how come my code pick a price from xml. result on browser is 636undefined

Comment: Not related to your problem, but better declare i as a variable in the local function scope: `for(var i=0;..`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`myXml('SYD','Bali')` call returns `undefined`, as you do not return anything in function body. So

```
document.write(myXml('SYD','Bali'));
```

will print `"undefined"` . Just replace above code with this:

```
myXml('SYD','Bali');
```

Answer (score 1):

Engineer is correct, or better return the value from your myXml function.

so, document.write(undefined) wont occur and you may not get the above error.